# Compiler error in Haskell code

Tags: haskell, elliptic-curve

I am trying to write  elliptic curve point addition using where clause. I am getting compiler error but when i translated the same code using let in expression , it works fine. Could some one please tell me what is wrong with this code. Full source code [ http://hpaste.org/49174 ] 

Thank you

Mukesh Tiwari

```
{--
--add points of elliptic curve using where clause getting compiler error
addPoints :: Elliptic -> Point -> Point -> Either Point Integer
addPoints _ Identity p_2 = Left p_2
addPoints _ p_1 Identity = Left p_1
addPoints ( Conelliptic a b n ) ( Conpoint x_p y_p ) ( Conpoint x_q y_q )  
    | x_p /= x_q =  case ( ( Conpoint x_r y_r ) , d ) of
                        ( _ , 1 ) -> Left ( Conpoint x_r y_r )
                        ( _ , d' ) -> Right d'
                      where
                                [ u , v , d ] = extended_gcd ( x_p - x_q ) n
                                s = mod ( ( y_p - y_q ) * u ) n
                                x_r = mod ( s*s - x_p - x_q ) n
                                y_r = mod ( -y_p - s * ( x_r - x_p ) ) n
    | otherwise =   if mod ( y_p + y_q ) n == 0 then Left Identity
                     else  case ( ( Conpoint x_r y_r ) , d ) of
                                ( _ , 1 ) -> Left ( Conpoint x_r y_r )
                                ( _ , d' ) -> Right d'
                            where
                                [ u , v , d ] = extended_gcd ( 2 * y_p ) n
                                s = mod ( ( 3 * x_p * x_p + a ) * u ) n
                                x_r = mod ( s * s - 2 * x_p ) n
                                y_r = mod ( -y_p - s * ( x_r - x_p ) ) n 

--}


--add points of elliptic curve let in clause and its working
addPoints::Elliptic->Point->Point-> Either Point Integer
addPoints _ Identity p_2 = Left p_2
addPoints _ p_1 Identity = Left p_1
addPoints ( Conelliptic a b n ) ( Conpoint x_p y_p ) ( Conpoint x_q y_q )
| x_p /= x_q = let
           [ u , v , d ] = extended_gcd (x_p-x_q) n
           s = mod  ( ( y_p - y_q ) * u ) n
           x_r = mod ( s * s - x_p - x_q ) n
           y_r= mod ( -y_p - s * ( x_r - x_p ) ) n
         in case ( ( Conpoint x_r y_r ) , d ) of
          ( _ , 1 ) -> Left ( Conpoint x_r y_r )
          ( _ , d' ) -> Right d'
| otherwise = if mod ( y_p + y_q ) n == 0 then Left Identity
         else  let
              [ u , v , d ] = extended_gcd ( 2*y_p ) n
              s = mod  ( ( 3 * x_p * x_p + a ) * u ) n
              x_r = mod ( s * s - 2 * x_p ) n
              y_r = mod ( -y_p - s * ( x_r - x_p ) ) n
           in case ( ( Conpoint x_r y_r ) , d ) of
                            ( _ , 1 )-> Left (Conpoint x_r y_r)
                            ( _ , d' ) -> Right d'
```

Comment: Could you pleast post the compiler error? This would be very helpful for those who want to help you.

Comment: I could not find an error. Both ways (the first and the second) compile without problems on my machine. (Using GHC 7)

Comment: Elliptic_Len.hs:59:8: parse error on input `|'
Failed, modules loaded: none. ghc-6.12.1

Comment: [This](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1869832/elliptic.hs) is the version I copyied from hpaste. Please double check whether it is the same as yours. Such errors may be related to the usage of *tabulators* instead of whitespace.

Comment: @FUZxxl yes but in this code addPoint function is let in clause which works fine . Try uncommenting the addPoint function using where clause .The same compiler error  http://ideone.com/hbdkd

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `where` blocks scope over function guards, so it's not possible to create a separate `where` for each guarded statement.  When ghc encounters the `where` on line 59, it automatically ends the function declaration and expects a new declaration to follow, which makes the `|` an error because it's not a valid declaration.  It works with a let-expression because `let` and `where` are different parts of the language.  The [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Let_vs._Where) has more information on this topic.